# Можно ли вставить С# WFA на сайт ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net

У меня есть сайт ASP.NET. Так как я сначала работал с WFA(Windows Forms Application), а не с ASP.NET, сначала я создал простое приложение формы. Но, как мы знаем, WFA работает только на Windows, и поэтому я захотел переместить приложение на сайт. Естественно у нас есть XML приложения и собственно говоря код. Возникает вопрос - могу ли я поместить свое приложения на сайт, взяв XML и исполняющий код программы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите.
Частично это можно, частично нет.

Если ваш код разделен на модель, контроллер/VM и представление, вы можете легко перенести на ASP.NET-приложение вашу модель. Она будет такой же, часто вовсе без изменений.

VM/контроллер, судя по всему, нужно будет подправлять, а то и переписать заново.

А представление (View) нужно будет просто выкинуть, т. к. у вас полностью другой метод показа информации пользователю.

---

А если у вас нету разделения на слои, тогда всё хуже. Я бы посоветовал тогда отделить модель, её можно будет перенести. Остальное скорее всего нет.

---

О переносе готовой программы, чтобы «вот так просто взяло и заработало», не может идти и речи. Увы.